# Is it possible to run a KSH command within an expect script?

Tags: ksh, expect, subshell

I simply want to source KSH with:

. ./.kshrc

within an expect script.

Is it possible to source KSH and run a KSH command within an expect script?

Comment: Update your question with what you've tried and your results.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just launch a ksh interpreter to run it in:

```
exec ksh -c {. ./.kshrc; some_command}
```